# How could I pass a non default constructor object to Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I didn't had much luck so far.
I am having an input of a submit type in my View:

```
<input type="submit" 
       value="Remove Question" 
       class="btn btn-outline-danger" 
       formaction=@Url.Action("Survey_RemoveQuestion", 
                              new Survey_Question_Wrapper() { 
                                  Survey = Model, 
                                  Question = Model.Questions[i] })/>
```

In my controller I have a handler, which looks like this:

```
  public ActionResult Survey_RemoveQuestion(Survey_Question_Wrapper s)
  {
      s.Survey.Questions.Remove(s.Question);
      return View("SurveyEdit", s.Survey);
  }
```

The Survey_Question_Wrapper has 2 constructors: a default empty one and the one, who accepts 2 parameters and assigns them to fields.

The problem which I am struggle with, is that the Survey_RemoveQuestion method
is invoked with an object, build with the default constructor, so his fields are null's.

I believe there is something obvious I am missing. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to send back the same data back to the controller that the controller just sent to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the problem is not relevant with `Survey_Question_Wrapper` constructors. You are trying to pass the complex types to controller via `GET`. You can't send the complex types directly like that.

You should serialize it and send it as string. (I used `Json.Net`, you can use another library)

```
    <input type = "submit"
    value="Remove Question" 
    class="btn btn-outline-danger" 
    formaction=@Url.Action("Survey_RemoveQuestion", 
    new
    {
        s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Survey_Question_Wrapper
            {
                Survey = Model,
                Question = Model.Questions[i]
            }
        )
    })/>
```

And controller part looks like;

```
  public ActionResult Survey_RemoveQuestion(string s)
  {
      //Deserialize it
      var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Survey_Question_Wrapper>(s);
      obj.Survey.Questions.Remove(obj.Question);
      return View("SurveyEdit", obj.Survey);
  }
```

Also, if you want to send complex types to server, its proper way to perform it using `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: Rainman, thank you, that's a way to do it. As well - may I ask you one more: whenever I am putting an annotation to the Action [HttpPost] - I am not able to access it from view. How could I put it as a POST request?

Comment: You can create a hidden input (input type="hidden") and serialize inside it as value. So, the serialized string is passed via post. Also, the hidden input should be inside of the form action.

Comment: I have an observation: when I serialize the Model - the data is not persisted. That means, that the form values are not passed.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the model via post or get ?

Comment: I have annotated the action with [HttpPost], but I did not created a hidden input as you suggested. Instead I am passing a serialized string directly to the Controller.

Comment: But if you mention as HttpPost, the action parameters expect that are passed by post not get. You should pass it as post.

Comment: Probably I am understanding it incorrect: if I am annotating a Controller action with [HttpPost] - that means, that it Expects an POST action? In this case - how can I flag my action in the View as a Post action?

Comment: "how can I flag my action in the View as a Post action?" there is no required for flag. Decorate your view the parameters which are sent as post or get. Also, "form action" already performs post.

Comment: This is poor advice. The model clearly contains a collection so there is a very good chance that the request will exceed the query string limit and throw an exception. And passing back exactly the same data to the controller that the controller just sent to the view is just crazy.